# When I click on a radio button, it scrolls to the top of the grid. How to prevent it?

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

When clicking on a radio button, it scrolls to the top of the grid that is within a page.

How can I prevent from jumping the scroll to the top of the grid within a page when clicking the radio button?

Tried switching from position: absolute to relative, adding top: auto but none of them worked. Thank you in advance!

**HTML Code:**

```
<div>
<section class="top-table  head-row-2">
<div class="grid fixed-head head-row-2" style="height: 130px">
  <table class="tblAlienQuestions">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="spacehh type1"><div><span>Type</span></div> </th>
        <th class="spacehh type2"><div><span>Is Anyone in the<br />Household?</span></div></th>
        <th class="spacehh type3"><div><span>Remove</span></div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let alien of ActiveDetail; let i = index" class="{{getStatusType(alien?.status)}}" [ngClass]="{'rowdisabled': DisableEnableQuestionListRows(alien)  }">
        <td (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, '')">{{alien?.QuestionText}}</td>
        <td>
          <span *ngIf="alien?.HhMember != ''" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, 'DETAIL')">
            {{alien?.HhMember}} &emsp;&emsp;
          </span>

          <span *ngIf="alien?.HhMember != '' && alien?.isDocSufficientFlag ==true" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, 'DETAIL')">
            <span class="fa fa-check" style="color: green"></span>
          </span>

          <span *ngIf="alien?.HhMember != '' && alien?.isDocSufficientFlag ==false" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, 'DETAIL')">
            <span class="fa fa-exclamation" style="color: yellow"></span>
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="EdicSummary != alien?.AlienQuestionEdicName && alien?.HhMember == '' "><input type="radio" value="Y" [(ngModel)]="alien.HasThisCondition" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i,'Y')" name="HasCondition{{i}}">YES &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</span>

          <span *ngIf="EdicSummary != alien?.AlienQuestionEdicName && alien?.HhMember == '' "><input type="radio" value="N" [(ngModel)]="alien.HasThisCondition" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, 'N')" name="HasCondition{{i}}">NO </span>
          
          <span *ngIf="EdicSummary == alien?.AlienQuestionEdicName" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, '')">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</span>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center verify-checkbox">
          <span *ngIf="alien?.HhMember != '' && alien.HasThisCondition != null" (click)="IsRemoveEdic(alien)"><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="alien.IsRemoveEdic" [checked]="alien.IsRemoveEdic" name="IsRemoveEdic" /></span>
          <span *ngIf="alien.HasThisCondition == null"></span>
          
          <span *ngIf="EdicSummary == alien?.AlienQuestionEdicName" (click)="OnSelectAlienType(alien,i, '')">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
    input[type='checkbox'] {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}


input[type='radio'] {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.type1 {
  width:60%;
}

.type2 {
  width: 30%;
}

.type3 {
  width: 10%;
}


.rowdisabled {
  color: #89aeb7 !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
  /*#89aeb7*/
}


.tblAlienQuestions {
  font-family: Lato-Regular,Arial !important;
  color: black !important;
  font-size:13px;
  // font-style:normal !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

OnSelectAlienType() code that is causing the issue as below. Not sure what is wrong with it.

```
 OnSelectAlienType(activeRecord: AlientypeQuestionList, index: number, selected :string) {
    if (!IsNullorEmptyString(selected)) {
      activeRecord.HasThisCondition = selected;
    }
    else if (activeRecord.HasThisCondition == "N") {
      selected = "Select";
    }
       
    else if (!IsNullorEmptyString(activeRecord.HhMember)) {
      selected = "DETAIL";
    }
    
    switch (selected) {
      case "Y": {
        this.addButtonEnable = true;
        activeRecord.Flag = SelectedAlienCondition.AddYesVal;
        if (IsNullorEmptyString(activeRecord.HasThisCondition)) {
          activeRecord.HasThisCondition = "Y";
        }
        break;
      }
      case "N": {
        this.addButtonEnable = true;
        activeRecord.Flag = SelectedAlienCondition.AddNoVal;
        if (IsNullorEmptyString(activeRecord.HasThisCondition)) {
          activeRecord.HasThisCondition = "N";
        }
        break;
      }
      case "DETAIL": {
        if (activeRecord.HhMember && activeRecord.HhMember != "") {
          activeRecord.Flag = SelectedAlienCondition.DetailVal;
          activeRecord.HasThisCondition = "Y";
          this.setAddButtonEnable();
        }
        else {
          activeRecord.Flag = SelectedAlienCondition.Select;
        }
        break;
      }
      default: {
        this.addButtonEnable = true;
        if (activeRecord.AlienQuestionEdicName == immigrationedicnames.SUMM) {
          activeRecord.Flag = "SUMM";
        } else {
          activeRecord.Flag = SelectedAlienCondition.Select;
        }       
      }
    }    
    this.AddAlienIndividual.emit(activeRecord); 
  }
```

Comment: That's on mobile right ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler it's on browser application using Angular 12. Thanks!

Comment: Scrolling on focus/click is not a default behaviour, you have some code that triggering it. Check what `OnSelectAlienType()` does.

Comment: Please provide stackblitz of your code

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler you are correct. The click event seems to be causing an issue for scrolling up. I removed (click) from html and it fixes and doesn't seem to scroll up. I have updated the question to add the  OnSelectAlienType() function above. If you know if I am doing something wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having (click) event, (mousedown) event seems to resolve the scrolling to the top issue.